# How to send the multiple options of the checkbox in FormMail PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have this options, where I take the all options for my FormMail PHP:

```
<div class="form-checkbox">
    <label for="modulo-1"><input type="checkbox" class="" name="Modulo" id="modulo-1" value="Simples Led" /> Simples Led</label>
</div>
<div class="form-checkbox">
    <label for="modulo-2"><input type="checkbox" class="" name="Modulo" id="modulo-2" value="Simples Solar" /> Simples Solar</label>
</div>
<div class="form-checkbox">
    <label for="modulo-3"><input type="checkbox" class="" name="Modulo" id="modulo-3" value="Simples Eólico" /> Simples Eólico</label>
</div>
```

But, my archive PHP don't send all checked options.

This is my formMail in PHP. It create one list, but I could send all checked options in my form.

```
function parse_form($array) {
   $reserved_keys[] = "MAX_FILE_SIZE";
   $reserved_keys[] = "required";
   $reserved_keys[] = "redirect";
   $reserved_keys[] = "formlimpo";
   $reserved_keys[] = "require";
   $reserved_keys[] = "path_to_file";
   $reserved_keys[] = "recipient";
   $reserved_keys[] = "subject";
   $reserved_keys[] = "bgcolor";
   $reserved_keys[] = "text_color";
   $reserved_keys[] = "link_color";
   $reserved_keys[] = "vlink_color";
   $reserved_keys[] = "alink_color";
   $reserved_keys[] = "title";
   $reserved_keys[] = "missing_fields_redirect";
   $reserved_keys[] = "env_report";      $reserved_keys[] = "acao";

   if (count($array)) {
      while (list($key, $val) = each($array)) {
         $reserved_violation = 0;
         for ($ri=0; $ri<count($reserved_keys); $ri++) {
            if ($key == $reserved_keys[$ri]) {
               $reserved_violation = 1;
            }
         }
         if ($reserved_violation != 1) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
               $contenttemp = "<b>$key:</b><br>";
               for ($z=0;$zcount($val);$z++) {
                  $contenttemp .= "$val[$z]<br>";
               }
               $contenttemp .= "<br>\n";
               $content .= $contenttemp;
            } else {

                  if ($val) {
              $content .= "<span style='font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;'><b>$key</b> $val</span><br><hr style='border-top: 1px solid #ccc;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;'>\n";
                  }
            }

         }
      }
   }
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: Instead of having `name='Modulo'` you need to do `name='Modulo[]'` instead. The `[ ]` tells PHP that you are passing an array not a single value.

Comment: I tried put name='Modulo[]'. And, When I send. Appear this error message: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Error in this Line

```
for ($z=0;$zcount($val);$z++) {
```

I think the Error "Function name must be a string" comes frome here, 
better:

```
$count_val = count($val);
for ($z=0;$z < $count_val ;$z++) {
```

And the right Answer is you need to do

```
name="modulo[]"
```

Or another way is this:

```
<div class="form-checkbox">
   <label for="modulo-1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" name="Modulo1" id="modulo-1" value="Simples Led" /> Simples Led
   </label>
</div>
<div class="form-checkbox">
   <label for="modulo-2"> 
      <input type="checkbox" class="" name="Modulo2" id="modulo-2" value="Simples Solar" /> Simples Solar
   </label>
</div>
<div class="form-checkbox">
   <label for="modulo-3">
       <input type="checkbox" class="" name="Modulo3" id="modulo-3" value="Simples Eólico" /> Simples Eólico
   </label>
</div>
```